# Qt: is it possible to create a widget similar to Windows 7 Start menu?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

I would like to create a widget similar to the Windows 7 Start menu in Qt.
But this I mean a vertical list of buttons that, when hovered over/clicked, would expand a list of options **to the right** of them.

One way I thought of achieving this is making the QComboBox popup expand to the right of the combobox, instead of below it, but I have no idea how to do it or is it even possible:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QDialog *w = new QDialog();

QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *ComboBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();

mainLayout->addLayout(ComboBoxLayout);
mainLayout->addStretch();

QComboBox *box1 = new QComboBox(w);
QComboBox *box2 = new QComboBox(w);
QComboBox *box3 = new QComboBox(w);

box1->addItem("Option 1");
box1->addItem("Option 2");
box1->addItem("Option 3");

box2->addItem("Option 1");
box2->addItem("Option 2");
box2->addItem("Option 3");

box3->addItem("Option 1");
box3->addItem("Option 2");
box3->addItem("Option 3");

ComboBoxLayout->addWidget(box1);
ComboBoxLayout->addWidget(box2);
ComboBoxLayout->addWidget(box3);
ComboBoxLayout->addStretch();

w->setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200);
w->setLayout(mainLayout);
w->show();
```

If you have any suggestions how to achieve the same effect a different way, please share it.

**Edit:** `QMenuBar` did the job. Thank you!

Comment: Using QML is a possibility you consider?

Comment: i think you have to write a new class inheriting from qwidget,

Comment: @danielfranca yep, QML is fine with me.

Comment: @YangKui So you suggest creating a custom widget from scratch?

Comment: Isn't  `QMenuBar` the best solution this way?

Comment: I donot think you can custom the direction of popup widget with a function call or a stylesheet , writing from scratch may be even faster than googling around.

Comment: Default direction of popup `QMenuBar` is the right direction.

Comment: I'll play around with QMenuBar and will tell you if it is exactly what I am looking for, but after seeing the documentation it looks very promising!

Comment: QMenuBar is what I was searching for. Thank you very much!